# Android app connection exception to NIO server socket

Tags: java, android, nio, serversocket

I am trying to trace a request originating from android  and send some data to serversocket at each hop. I am using below code to execute client and send data to ServerSocket at each hop (tomcats having servlet projects) and they are able to send and connect.

However when I try to use same below code in android app running on emulator on same machine. It throws me timeout error.

```
InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress(hostAdress,
                    SocketServerPORT);
            SocketChannel client = SocketChannel.open(hostAddress);
```

after open execution gives me

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.102 (port 8090): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-24 13:25:58.140 3382-3424/app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
01-24 13:25:58.140 3382-3424/app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:110)
01-24 13:25:58.140 3382-3424/app W/System.err:  .....
```

what could possibly be wrong here?

my app has

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />.
```

I have also used

```
Socket socket = new Socket(hostaddress,port)
```

It throws same exception.

Comment: This is a network connectivity problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: looks like so .I am not sure but strongly suspect that android emulator requires some tweaking (port forwarding or something ).  I have made temporary arrangement with one more intermediate tomcat to acheive conectivity between  android and serversocket. will come back post here when I succeed.